# TypeError - React/Redux Component Function Requiring New Syntax

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Does anyone have an idea what could be causing the following error?

> ReactCompositeComponent.js:321 Uncaught TypeError: Failed to construct
>   'Notification': Please use the 'new' operator, this DOM object
>   constructor cannot be called as a function.

I'm basically recreating the react [todoApp](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/ExampleTodoList.html) for React/Redux as a starting point. The Notification component is as follows:

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react'

const Notification = ({ myProp }) => (
  <li>
    --My Notification HTML--
  </li>
)

Notification.propTypes = {
  myProp: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
}

export default Notification
```

I've NEVER run into this issue in a react/redux app before and I'm absolutely clueless as to where to start looking for the source of the error. If it helps, I started with [this](https://github.com/lcjnil/react-redux-scaffold) scaffolding, though I've removed the router. I just need potential causes, though it's even better if you can identify the exact problem. If you need more information, I can provide it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Silly me. I forgot to import the Notification's component inside the component that renders it. Always after I post the question and spend a half hour tracking down the problem. :P